# Puppeteer - getting throw new error sometimes appear

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I try to do some web scrapping with puppeteer,my script work but sometimes, without reason in my comprehension, i get this error :

```
file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/assert.js:23
        throw new Error(message);
              ^
Error
    at assert (file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/assert.js:23:15)
    at FrameManager._FrameManager_onFrameAttached (file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:318:5)
    at file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/FrameManager.js:89:103
    at file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:49:68
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.emit (file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/vendor/mitt/src/index.js:49:43)
    at CDPSession.emit (file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/EventEmitter.js:66:22)  
    at CDPSession._onMessage (file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:273:18)
    at Connection._Connection_onMessage (file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/common/Connection.js:160:21)
    at WebSocket.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Users/aemba/OneDrive/Bureau/nodejs/octopart-scraping/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/esm/puppeteer/node/NodeWebSocketTransport.js:37:32)
```

This error can be appear at the start, or on any url in my for loop. I think the crash arrive during the browser oppening but i'm not sure.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

let urls = [
            "https://octopart.com/search?q=SI7020-A20-GM1&currency=USD&specs=0",
            "https://octopart.com/search?q=RN41N-I%2FRM&currency=USD&specs=0",
            "https://octopart.com/search?autosugg_idx=1&currency=USD&oq=adxl1004&q=adxl1004bcpz&specs=1",
            "https://octopart.com/search?q=SI7021-A20-GM1&currency=USD&specs=0"
          ];

(async () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  let url = urls[i];
  let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  try {
      let page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto(url, { 
        waitUntil: 'networkidle0'
      });
      await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
      const buttons = await page.$$('button[class="jsx-3623225293"')
      for (let btn of buttons) {
        await btn.click()
      }
      await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
      await page.waitForSelector('tbody');
      await page.waitForTimeout(2000);
      let data = [];
      data = await page.evaluate(() => {
        let d = new Date();
        var date = d.getFullYear()+'-'+(d.getMonth()+1)+'-'+d.getDate();

        let root = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("tbody > tr"));
        let components = root.map(component => ({
            distributor: component.querySelector("td:nth-child(2)").innerText,
            link: component.querySelector("td:nth-child(2) > div > a").href,
            stock: component.querySelector("td:nth-child(4)").innerText,
            price: (component.querySelector("td:nth-child(8)").innerText) ? component.querySelector("td:nth-child(8)").innerText : "missing",
            date: date,
            autorized: (component.querySelector("td:nth-child(1) > a") && component.querySelector("td:nth-child(1) > a").title) ? component.querySelector("td:nth-child(1) > a").title : "missing"
        }));
        return components;
      });
      console.log("data",data);
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  } finally {
      await browser.close();
    }
}})();
```

I try to add some page.waitForTimeout(2000) or error handling without success. I'm preety new to javascript and webscrapping, if someone have an idea for this error, it will be great.

Comment: Hi, why are you launching puppeteer inside a loop? The better way would be to open the puppeteer one time and open a new page inside the loop.

Comment: Also instead of waiting for 2 seconds. You should use load event of page.

page.once('load', () => console.log('Page loaded!'));

Comment: I try to launching puppeteer outside the loop, but with that the site detect me like a bot and add a complex captcha. I have replace waiting for 2 second by page.once. The problem are still here something. I have make many try, and the error appear frenquently when i start vs code. After 3 or 4 script running, this work better.

Comment: The error is not with your code, it is very likely a bug with puppeteer running on windows. You could probably mitigate it with launching puppeteer with extra flags. But I highly recommend you try apify-js, buy some proxies or add more wait time in your script. Opening a browser again and again for every request is a big anti-pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Pranav Choudhary for confirming my impression. The code error is displayed when opening the Chrome browser.
I start coding my script with the option:

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
```

But it didn't work without me understanding why. So I went to:

```
let browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
```

But after several researches, websites can block connections from headless scrappers, but you can bypass this blocking by adding users configuration after browser.newPage :

```
wait page.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.181 Safari/537.36");
```

With this configuration, my script works fine. Thank you all for the advice and good practices that I have noted.